# Screen response not as advertised?

Tags: display, refresh-rate

I recently bought a new 27" screen - a BENQ GL2760H.

When I scroll through / move graphics (in Photoshop) or scroll web pages, I notice a white trail (on dark backgrounds) and a dark trail (on light backgrounds) following any contrasting element.

According to the manufacturer this screen has a 2ms response time.

This really isn't my field of expertise but shouldn't a fast response time effectively prevent any issues like that? Could it be faulty or is there something else I should be looking at to fix this?

Comment: Did the manufacturer claim a "real response time" of 2ms for going from black to white or the "some gray to some other gray near it response time"? Both are advertised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues that the manufacturer claims that a fast response time will prevent is smearing and ghosting.
"Fast response time of 2ms GTG means speed without the smear. Fast-moving action and dramatic transitions will be rendered smoothly – without smearing or ghosting" (source - the Benq website product details for your monitor).

Smearing and ghosting occur when the monitor is unable to change rapidly enough to match a change in video signal. Instead of immediately changing from one picture to another, the picture changes slowly from the old to the new which results in both pictures being displayed simultaneously (at lower intensities). Slowly in this case is relative to the response of the human eye. Something around 10ms or above would cause this although all eyes vary.

Note that there is no standard for measuring response times and manufacturers are likely to cherry pick the kind of transitions (for example grey to grey) that have the fastest change.

The artefacts you describe are more likely to be due to slow software not redrawing the pixels of the video memory quickly enough (driver problems perhaps?). If you can easily see these effects, they will be occurring for much longer than 2ms.

Can you connect the monitor to a standard video source (eg dvd player or games console) ideally through the same input? Do you see the same artefacts? If not, the problem isn't the monitor's response time.